# Is there any issue to call dispatch_semaphore_signal in the block after dispatch_release(no ARC case)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, dispatch-async

1. does the following code has some issue when timeout (no ARC case)?
2. how about the dispatch_semaphore_signal is called after dispatch_release(semaphore)? I know a dispatch object is asynchronously deallocated once all references to it are released (the reference count becomes zero), so the reference of the semaphore is not 0 in the following code?
3. is it necessary to add __block for semaphore?

   ```
        dispatch_time_t timeout = DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER;
        if (waitTime > 0)
        {            
            timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, waitTime * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);  
        dispatch_barrier_async(_dispatchQueue, ^{
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        });

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, timeout);
        dispatch_release(semaphore);
   ```

thanks a lot!

Comment: I *think* you need to signal it if you reach the timeout otherwise the release will fail.

Comment: @skaak, thanks. you mean the reference of seamphore would not be 0 in this case, right? do I need to cancel the block first, then signal it?

Comment: No not the reference ... the semaphore count itself ... I think the semaphore will complain if you release it and the wait and signals don't balance. Since you have a signal that never fired I think you could just add another signal before the release to be sure the release will work. I don't think it matters if you signal more than you wait e.g. if it does not timeout but fires twice I think the release will be fine.

Comment: My head hurts! If you release yourself you also need to take care of the block so also I think yes you need to cancel it.

Comment: The problem is that after the timeout the semaphore may still signal at any time while you take care of the admin here. It is almost as if you need some syncing to do around the semaphore and its release.

Comment: @skaak, great! I think you are right, the wait and signals do not balance. if I add another signal before releasing in order to release semaphore, whether I will get some issue like "Use-after-free of dispatch_semaphore_t" when the block is fired(dispatch_semaphore_wait)

Comment: Thanks android! In ARC you would not need __block on the semaphore, I don't think here you need it either. I checked the manual and think the cancel block will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments.

I think you need something like this. The `done` variable needs to be synced / atomic and there are two places in the code that need to be synced on some common lock. In fact, since you only access `done` inside those pieces it does not need to be synced.

```
done = NO

dispatch_barrier ...
   stuff
   sync {
     if(!done)
       signal
       done = YES;
   }

wait with timeout
cancel block
sync {
  if( ! done )
    signal
    done = YES
}

// You can even test the logic as below
if DEBUG
{
  assert done == YES
}

release
```

I am not sure what the impact of cancel block will be in non ARC environment but think it will be fine.

This will balance the signals and waits and will cause the release to work and also prevent you from signalling the released semaphore.

Here is an outline implementation in Objective-C

```
    __block BOOL done = NO;
    NSObject * lock = NSObject.new;
    dispatch_semaphore_t s = dispatch_semaphore_create ( 0 );
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create( "bak",
                               dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class( DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT,
                                                   QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT,
                                                   DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT ) );

    dispatch_block_t block = dispatch_block_create ( DISPATCH_BLOCK_BARRIER, ^ {

        // Change this time to determine which one fires first
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

        @synchronized ( lock ) {

            if ( ! done )
            {
                done = YES;
                dispatch_semaphore_signal ( s );
                NSLog ( @"Inside fired" );
            }

        }

    } );

    // Start the block
    dispatch_async ( queue, block );

    // ... or change time here to determine which one fires first
    dispatch_semaphore_wait ( s, dispatch_time ( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC ) );

    @synchronized ( lock ) {

        if ( ! done )
        {
            done = YES;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal ( s );
            NSLog ( @"Outside fired" );
        }

    }

    // Done, release stuff *only* if not ARC
    dispatch_release ( s );
    dispatch_release ( queue );
    dispatch_release ( block );
    lock.release;
```

Comment: is there any way to use std::atomic in the block?

Comment: The dispatch_semaphore_wait() function decrements the semaphore. If the resulting value is less than zero, it waits for a signal from a thread that increments the semaphore by calling dispatch_semaphore_signal() before returning.  The timeout parameter is creatable with the dispatch_time(3) or dispatch_walltime(3) functions. If the timeout is reached without a signal being received, the semaphore is re-incremented before the function return, so that means we don't need dispatch_semaphore_signal if timeout case?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yes I think you are right, you do not need to signal the semaphore in order to release it. However, you still need the guard otherwise you can signal on the inside after the semaphore has been released. If the block cancel guarantees that execution stops immediately then that can also fall away.

Comment: I tested it in a program with ARC turned off - yes you can release without a balancing signal. From a few tests my code seems extremely conservative, you can get away with a lot less but of course what you cut also depends on other things e.g. when you release and how you cancel the block if the timeout is reached.